# How can I prevent Outlook 2010 from stripping my contact telephone numbers of their correct formatting?

Tags: windows-7, sync, microsoft-outlook-2010, gmail-contacts

I can see that there are similar questions about this for various versions of Outlook, but the answers don't quite make sense to me. Using the Windows dialing rules control panel seems to be quite complicated.

Let me explain: I'm in the UK. We have dialing rules that are different, depending on where you are and which device you use to call (mobile or landline). I want to sync my Gmail contacts with Oulook, so I purhcase Gsyncit. Unfortunately, when I set it up so that there would be two-way syncing, even though Gmail was set as the 'senior' source of contacts, Outlook would import the contacts, then strip some of them of the '+' symbol at the front of the number. Other numbers stored in Gmail Contacts start with '0' instead of '+44' and these are unaffected.

With that in mind, the Windows dialing rules 'fix' doesn't make sense to me. I'm not sure how putting in my local area code (eg, 01772 or 0207) will somehow prevent Outlook from stripping my contacts of the '+' symbol.

Is there a permanent fix that will stop Outlook from having any involvement in how it formats telephone numbers?

Comment: Is there actually a + button on UK phones that you have to press when you call a number that has a + in front of it?  Or is the + simply a visual formatting thing, that actually has nothing to do with the dialing?  What's the difference (when you dial) between '+44 (0)1256 784136' and '44 (0)1256 784136'?

Comment: Hi Bon, the answer is a bit unusual. +44 is often used by mobile phones to dial and store numbers, but when using landlines we would normally dial 0 instead. So I store numbers from my mobile, which uses Gmail Contacts. In turn, this is synced with Outlook, which then strips the +, syncs with Gmail as a contact update and makes the numbers undialable. Although it should be simple for me to grasp, it's causing me some difficulty.

Comment: so... when on your mobile phone, you actually bring up the alpha numeric keyboard, and put a plus sign in before the number, when you dial?  But when you are on a land line, you dial 0 in place of the plus sign?

Comment: This is where it gets strange: no. I would normally dial a '0', but if a call is incoming or if a contact is sent to me, the phone formats the number with a '+44' instead. So I have a mixture of such numbers stored in my phone.